# iOS app crashes on startup

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

The latest beta of the iOS app (1.3.2.217) crashes immediately after I open it.

It shortly flashes on, showing the previous state and then terminates. It still gives me notifications though, just the UI crashes.

Can this bug be fixed please?

The error log:

```
{"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 8.1 (12B411)","build_version":"1.3.2.217","symbolicated":true,"blame":[],"app_name":"Stack Exchange","bundleID":"com.stackexchange.ent.zaphod","name":"Stack Exchange","is_first_party":false,"app_version":"1.3.2","share_with_app_devs":true,"slice_uuid":"064d4aec-dc10-3146-b5b6-4c08fee8a1b2","adam_id":0}
Incident Identifier: 7538899F-FEEA-4AE3-894E-BC15D3DA1964
CrashReporter Key:   8c52defea363ebafac9e4bcca76c100c3e3bade1
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,2
Process:             Stack Exchange [70242]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/6685F3B8-BD0A-4926-B6B6-EFBAB50B7CFE/Stack Exchange.app/Stack Exchange
Identifier:          com.stackexchange.ent.zaphod
Version:             1.3.2.217 (1.3.2)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Date/Time:           2015-07-31 19:56:40.493 +0100
Launch Time:         2015-07-31 19:56:40.038 +0100
OS Version:          iOS 8.1 (12B411)
Report Version:      105
Exception Type:      EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:     0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000120095088
Triggered by Thread: 0
Dyld Error Message:  
  Library not loaded:@rpath/SwiftDiff.framework/SwiftDiff
  Referenced from:   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/6685F3B8-BD0A-4926-B6B6-EFBAB50B7CFE/Stack Exchange.app/Stack Exchange
  Reason:            image not found
  Dyld Version:      353.5
```

Comment: in case somebody would look for a similar problem: on IOS6 with the memo voice (inbuilt) app I solved the startup crash problem using ifile (jailbroken iphone). Go to var/mobile/library/caches then delete the whole folder com.apple.VoiceMemos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crash was fixed with version 1.3.2.218.